# How to make a successful JSON call from Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am baffled by this for very long now. I want to gain this precious knowledge of making JSON call properly. Help me Humans.

So I'm making a call exactly like this:

```
$.ajax({

        type    : "POST",
        url     : "http://quote.mythicalQuotes.com/unicorn/service/historical/json?callback=callme&symbols=APPL",
        dataType: "text",   
        cache   : false,       
        data    : My_Array, 
        error   : function(request,error){alert(request+" "+error); },            
        success : function(data) 
                { 
                    alert("Response" + data);  
                }//success 

}).fail(function(textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("error Error"); 
    console.log("The following error occured: "+ textStatus, errorThrown); });
```

But it fails and throws 'error' alert. Good Coding!

Now pasting "**http://quote.mythicalQuotes.com/unicorn/service/historical/chart/lite/json?callback=callme&symbols=APPL**" on my browser URL gives me nice JSON of format:

```
     callme(
        {
        "SYMB" : [
        {
        "DESCRIPTION" : "APPL,
        "BARS" : {

        "CB" :[
        {
        "lt" : "09-01-2011::20:00:00",
        "op" : "16.31",
        "cl" : "15.22",
        "hi" : "16.45",
        "lo" : "14.72",
        "v" : "17768019"
        },
        {
        "lt" : "09-02-2011::20:00:00",
        "op" : "15.22",
        "cl" : "14.22",
        "hi" : "19.45",
        "lo" : "10.72",
        "v" : "17768000"
        }
        ]
        }
        ]
        })
```

So what atrocity am I doing here which is provoking my anger toward this particular Javascript semantics/syntactics?

Couple of reasons I thought which might cause this.
1. Same origin policy.
2. Wrong JSON format being return.
3. Stupidity of my code.

Please help.

Comment: Is your code on the `quote.mythicalQuotes.com` domain? If not, then #1 might get in your way since you say you want `JSON`, I can't test the link to find out if it supports `JSONP`

Comment: change `dataType: 'text'` to `dataType: 'jsonp'`. The format you're trying to use is `jsonp` where the padding is the `callback`. The `callback` should have the entire JSON string inside of it, and you'll be able to parse that string and retrieve your data.

Comment: I believe its not in the same domain. In that case how can I make a cross domain call. Is this cross domain policy a browser feature? Do all browser restrict this?

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you change to dataType jsonp, it is no longer a `POST`, however it should still work since the api you are referencing works with `GET`

Comment: @srijan If you change to JSONP and GET rather than text and POST, it should work.

Comment: @Kevin But I'm getting a parseError now from
error   : function(request,error){alert(request+" "+error); },

Comment: @srijan That's a much better error. That means the jsonp callback being returned isn't what jQuery expects it to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a JSONP-type response.  Add `dataType: jsonp` to the JQuery AJAX request.  Since you're also specifying the callback function explicitly, add `jsonpCallback: callme` also.  See the [JQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info (scroll down to the "dataType" section).

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonpCallback: "callme",
    // ...
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);  // should show the JSON:  { "SYMB" : ... }
    }
});
```

You mentioned the cross-domain policy; the JSONP spec is a workaround for this policy blocking cross-domain requests.  The idea is that, rather than returning data, the server returns a Javascript snippet containing data.  The client then executes the returned function to retrieve the data.  The JQuery `ajax` method has built-in functionality to handle all this "behind the scenes".

Comment: So that means, the start of the returned 'thing' callme(....) is actually a function which returns the actual data (within its parenthesis)? is that correct? And also, what is the difference between the callme function and the "success" function?

Comment: @srija Yes -- but you don't need to worry about *callme* in the response if you're using the JQuery above.  The response you see will only be the inside JSON.  In other words, the "success" method's parameter will contain the JSON, stripped of the "callme" wrapper.

Comment: You sir are awesome. Thank you for enlightening me on A-Z of ajax call.